# How to select last year of inclusion within repeated measures of each patient?

Tags: repeated-measures, spss

I have an SPSS file with each patient being recorded multiple times (1-8 times per patient). Each record is a different row in SPSS (I have over 4000 records). Now, I would like to select the latest year of inclusion of each patient. However, I cannot figure out how to do that. So for example, I would like to select the year 2019 of patient 1 (since 2019 is the last year the patient participated)and the year 2009 of patient 2.

1    2017
1    2018
1    2019
2    2008
2    2009

I hope someone can help me with how to do it. So far, I've tried a lot of options but I cannot find an answer. Thanks for helping me out. I'm using IBM SPSS Statistics version 23.

Sam

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AGGREGATE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_24.0.0/spss/base/syn_aggregate.html) by patient id to create a new variable that computes the last year. Then select only cases with the same year.

First build a random dataset to check the method.

```
set rng=mc seed=17760704.
new file.
input program.
    numeric id (f5) year (f4) some_data (f6.3).
    loop #i=1 to 200.
        compute #n=trunc(rv.uniform(1,10)).
        loop #j=1 to #n.
            compute year=trunc(rv.uniform(2000,2010)).
            compute some_data=rv.normal(0,1).
            compute id=#i.
            end case.
        end loop.
    end loop.
    end file.
end input program.
execute.
```

Two ways to solve the problem with AGGREGATE: either compute the maximum year in each group, or presort by id/year and get the last year in each id group.

```
aggregate /outfile=* mode=addvariables /break=id /maxyear=max(year).
select if year=maxyear.
execute.
```

Second method:

```
sort cases id year.
aggregate /outfile=* mode=addvariables /presorted /break=id /maxyear=last(year).
select if year=maxyear.
execute.
```

Note that if a patient may have several records with the same year, then the commands above will keep all cases matching the *last* year.

Comment: Wow thanks for your response! I will try that today :). Do to think it will work as well when the last year of inclusion differs? Some of my patients participates untill 2018 and some dropped out earlier.

Comment: @Samm__ Yes, it will select the last year for each patient.